# ActionBar tabs -- set width to wrap content?

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

I want the width of each tab to be appropriate for its content.  This is what I have for my tab style.  The padding is working just fine.  But the width setting doesn't seem to do anything -- all tabs have the same width.

```
<style name="MyActionBarTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```